# Random Distribution with Params within Data Frame

Tags: r, dataframe, random

I'm attempting to generate random losses within a data frame, using pre-specified variable. What I'm interested in is the "rand.num" variable - what is a better / more efficient way to generate that random number? I get what I'm looking for using the below, but when I run it with my full table, and for many simulations, I'm having run time issues.

```r
data <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(1, 2500, 2500, 5000), 2, 2)) #take this as given

colnames(data) <- c("Lower", "Upper") #lower & upper bound of uniform distribution

rand.num.1 <- rdunif(1, data[1,1],  data[1,2])

rand.num.2 <- rdunif(1, data[2,1],  data[2,2])

data$rand.num <- c(rand.num.1, rand.num.2)

print(data)
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the random sampling all in one go with `runif` and truncate:

```
data$rand.num <- floor(runif(nrow(data), data$Lower, data$Upper + 1))
```

Comment: Thank you! That seemed to work!